# Is there a non-deterministic version of the complexity class PP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity

From a quick skim of the literature (and complexity zoo), there doesn't seem to be a non-deterministic version of PP. Is there a reason for this (e.g. PP=non-deterministic PP?)

Edit: Perhaps I phrased the question poorly: I was thinking more along the lines of BPP's relation to MA? Is there an equivalent version of an interactive proof system where Merlin needs only convince Arthur with probability >1/2?

Comment: How would such a complexity class be defined?

Comment: Perhaps I phrased the question poorly: I was thinking more along the lines of BPP's relation to MA? Is there an equivalent version of an interactive proof system where Merlin needs only convince Arthur with probability >1/2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not really make sense to define an “X-version of class Y”, this is a misguided viewpoint. You define classes because they are *useful* or *interesting* in whatever context you are investigating, not to fill a slot in an imaginary table. So, what would count as a nondeterministic version of PP depends very much on what you intend to *do* with the class.

Having said that, in view of $\mathrm{P^{\|PP}=PP}$, one reasonable option is to define a nondeterministic version of PP as $\mathrm{NP^{\|PP}}$, which equals $\exists\mathrm{PP}$.

Concerning the edit: $\exists\mathrm{PP}$ indeed coincides with the variant of MA with acceptance probability $>1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what does ||PP mean in this case? I can't find any references to it (in the complexity zoo or otherwise). Thanks again!

Comment: $\mathrm P^{\|X}$ denotes polynomial time with parallel (= nonadaptive) access to oracle $X$.

Answer (score 10):

PP is defined as a probabilistic class and we don't normally think of nondeterministic versions of any of these classes (as far as I'm aware). In a sense probabilistic classes and nondeterministic ones are already on the same spectrum -- let me illustrate. We can define a language to be in PP if there's a randomized poly-time TM ("RPTM") that on a yes instance accepts with $> 0.5$ probability and on a no instance accepts with $\leq 0.5$ probability. Similarly we can define a language to be in NP if there's a RPTM accepting yes-instances w.prob $> 0$ and accepting no-instances w.prob $0$. (Convince yourself of this if you haven't before.) BPP corresponds to probability thresholds $\geq 2/3$ and $\leq 1/3$ while RP corresponds to $\geq 1/2$ and $0$.

So you see, PP can already be viewed as a "nondeterministic" version of P, but with different requirements as compared to NP.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased the question poorly: I was thinking more along the lines of BPP's relation to MA? Is there an equivalent version of an interactive proof system where Merlin needs only convince Arthur with probability >1/2?